# Cant get Subprocess.Popen to run parameters but batch will

Tags: python, subprocess

```
java -jar "Some/File/Path" -account AccountEmail -proxy "SomeIP"
```

This example will work in a batch file.

```
SubprocessCommand = ['java', '-jar', 'Some/File/Path',
'-account RandomEmail@gmail.com', '-proxy "111.111.11.111"']
subprocess.Popen(SubprocessCommand, shell=True)
```

However this will not work in python, anyone know what I did wrong? my warnings are

```
2021-04-05 14:13:47 [WARN] Unsupported quick start argument: -account RandomEmail@gmail.com
2021-04-05 14:13:47 [WARN] Unsupported quick start argument: -proxy "111.111.11.111"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating out all of your arguments into individual list items.

```
SubprocessCommand = ['java', '-jar', 'Some/File/Path','-account', 'RandomEmail@gmail.com', '-proxy', '111.111.11.111']
subprocess.Popen(SubprocessCommand, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Where did you get that idea from? I would have never thought of it. I will submit this as answer in 6 minutes because it wont let me till then.

Comment: I've used subprocess in the past and run into the same problem before. Glad it was helpful!